# Regex to extract consent form response data?

Tags: regex, jmeter

i am new to jmeter and i am using regular expression extractor to extract document number which is between

```
<showDocument> 834446$$$$1601Consent </showDocument>
```

which field should i check Body or Response Header

Comment: is that xml? then regexes are exactly the WRONG thing to use...

Comment: i don't know jmeter but i guess that this is an XML: [Why you are wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1):

The relevant Regular Expression Configuration would be:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `showDocument`
- Regular Expression: `<showDocument>(.+?)</showDocument>`
- Template: `$1$`

[image: Regex Tester]

You can access extracted value as `${showDocument}` where required. See [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) chapter of JMeter User Manual for more details

By the way, your response part looks like XML so it might be easier and better to consider using [XPath Extractor](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) instead. In that case [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp) would be extremely helpful.